# TestNg grouping

Tags: java, testing, testng, testng-annotation-test

We are using testNg as our test framework, where in we use @groups annotation for running specific tests. How can we customize this annotation to make the groups specified in the build target are considered in 'AND' instead of 'OR'.

```java
@groups({'group1', 'group2'})
public void test1

@groups({'group1', 'group3'})
public void test2
```

if we pass groups as `{group1,group2}`, then `test1` should be the only test case which gets triggered. Currently, using the default implementation both `test1` and `test2` get triggered because the annotation considers both groups in 'or' instead of 'and'

Comment: Suppose test2 is defined with `@Test(groups = {"group1", "group2", "group3"})`, then should test2 be included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current implementation is such that, **If any one of the groups specified in the test method matches with any one group specified in your suite file, then the test is included to run.**

Currently there are no provisions to change this implementation of "any match" to "all match". But you could achieve the same using `IMethodInterceptor`.

*(Also, for the specific example in question, you could have achieved the desired result by mentioning `group3` as an excluded group. But this will not work in many other scenarios).*

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyInterceptor implements IMethodInterceptor {
    
    @Override
    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
        String[] includedGroups = context.getIncludedGroups();
        Arrays.sort(includedGroups);

        List<IMethodInstance> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(IMethodInstance m : methods) {
            String[] groups = m.getMethod().getGroups();
            Arrays.sort(groups);

            // logic could be changed here if exact match is not required.
            if(Arrays.equals(includedGroups, groups)) {
                newList.add(m);
            }
        }

        return newList;
    }
}
```

Then on top of your test class, use the `@Listeners` annotation.

```java
@Listeners(value = MyInterceptor.class)
public class MyTestClass {
}
```